# How to GET Redis JSON data

Tags: json, redis

I am, unfortunately, using an out dated Redis so it does not support the new JSON commands, so I am doing a `JSON.Stringify(object)` and doing a redis `SET`
which stores the key like so:

```
"{\"id\":\"123\",\"person\":\"Joe\""}"
```

What Redis command can I do to get this key based off the `id`?

I was trying to play around with

```
redis-cli get id:123
```

but this was not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I did pass the whole object as the key, perhaps there is an easier way to set the ID as the key and then the object as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Redis SET command](https://redis.io/commands/set) associates a *key* with a *value*. What that key and value are is up to you; Redis doesn't interpret them in any way, or extract them from a single object, you pass them as two arguments.

For instance:

- `SET hello world` associates the key "hello" with the value "world"
- `SET "address-123" "123 Blah St, Nashville, TN 12345"` associates the key `"address-123"` with the value `"123 Blah St, Nashville, TN 12345"`
- `SET "6b091891-58eb-4563-9f9b-8ac893cf4725" "{\"id\":\"6b091891-58eb-4563-9f9b-8ac893cf4725\",\"address\":\"123 Blah St, Nashville, TN 12345\""}"` associates the key `"6b091891-58eb-4563-9f9b-8ac893cf4725"` with the value `"{\"id\":\"6b091891-58eb-4563-9f9b-8ac893cf4725\",\"address\":\"123 Blah St, Nashville, TN 12345\""}"`

The [GET command](https://redis.io/commands/get) then retrieves the *value* based on the *key*. So, given the above SET commands:

- `GET hello` will return `"world"`
- `GET "address-123"` will return `"123 Blah St, Nashville, TN 12345"`
- `GET "6b091891-58eb-4563-9f9b-8ac893cf4725"` will return `"{\"id\":\"6b091891-58eb-4563-9f9b-8ac893cf4725\",\"address\":\"123 Blah St, Nashville, TN 12345\""}"`

Using the entire object as the key doesn't make much sense, because in order to look it up again, you need exactly the same object - in which case, there's nothing to look up.